# How can inherited in the application of the theme from the library? Android

Tags: android, styles, android-theme

I made a custom library. The library has a theme Theme_Amber. I added this library to my project. How can I be inherited in the application of the theme from the library?
I want to be inherited just as inherited from android theme

I wrote this

But the application crash with an error:
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AppCompatActivity supports only Theme.AppCompat or themes inherited from Theme.AppCompat. If you want to use your custom theme, set it's parent theme as Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: theme in library Theme_Amber inherited from @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. Can I get access to the theme in the library? And inherit the theme of the project from Theme_Amber

Comment: How did you add the library to your project?

Comment: through import module

Comment: If the studio doesn't show an error when you specify the theme in the manifest, it means it is indeed picking it up from the library. Can you update the question with the source for your theme?